# proxy_pass in nginx to private IP of EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, proxy, amazon-ec2, resque

I have two Amazon EC2 instances. Let me call them X and Y. I have nginx installed on both of them. Y has [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) running on port `3000`. Only X has a public IP and domain example.com. Suppose private IP of Y is `15.0.0.10`

What I want is that all the requests come to X. And only if the request url matches the pattern `/resque`, then it should be handled by Y at `localhost:3000/overview`, which is the resque web interface. It seems like this can be done using proxy_pass in nginx config.

So, In nginx.conf, I have added the following :

```
location /resque {
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    allow all;

    proxy_pass  http://15.0.0.10:3000/overview;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

But now, when I visit `http://example.com/resque` from my web browser, it shows `502 Bad Gateway`.

In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` on X,

```
2014/02/27 10:27:16 [error] 12559#0: *2588 connect() failed (111: Connection 
refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.201.181.82, server: _, 
request: "GET /resque HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://15.0.0.10:3000/overview", 
host: "example.com"
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong and how to fix this ?

Comment: Does your resque listens on 15.0.0.10:3000? Probably it listens to localhost:3000.

Comment: @alexeyten They both should be same

Comment: No. localhost is 127.0.0.1 and is accessible only from the same machine.

Comment: does `http://15.0.0.10:3000/overview` work by it self ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the server should be running on 0.0.0.0 if it needs to be reachable by addressing the IP of the instance.

So to solve my problem, I stopped the server running resque on 127.0.0.1:3000 and restarted it to bind to 0.0.0.0:3000. Rest everything remains the same as above and it works. Thanks.

For reference : [Curl amazon EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067711/curl-amazon-ec2-instance)