# Curl amazon EC2 instance

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web server running on an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance at port 3000. `15.0.0.10` is the private ip of this EC2 instance.

After I ssh into this instance and run the following command `curl localhost:3000/index.html`, it returns me the html source of my index.html page.

But when I run `curl 15.0.0.10:3000/index.html`, it says :

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

1. Why is this happening ?
2. What can I do to make the second command also return the content?

Comment: Yes. In eth0 in output of ifconfig, `inet addr:15.0.0.10`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ensure that the server is running on 0.0.0.0 if you need it to be reachable by addressing **any** IP of the instance.

If you have started it on localhost (127.0.0.1), then the behavior is expected. You can stop the server and re-start it to bind to 0.0.0.0:3000. Things should work.