# amazon ec2 - Couldn't resolve host

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm a nooob devops guy in town. I've a nodejs app running on amazon instance pointing to DNS's.
[image: Prayag]

```
                                Route53 screenshot
```

### Problem

**when I try to reach the subdomain,** I get

```
curl -i http://site.soothsayer.co/
curl: (7) Failed connect to site.soothsayer.co:80; Connection timed out
```

**or**

```
$ curl -i http://site.soothsayer.co/
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Via: 1.1 Comverse 6.2.23
Content-Length: 287

<!DOCTYPE html PUbliC "-//W3C//Dtd XHTML basic 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/tr/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" style="font-family:arial">
Error: Requested url content cannot be resolved.
</body>
</html>
```

### Debugging

**nslookup result is**

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
site.soothsayer.co  canonical name = internal-p-site-us-east-1-1077850846.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   internal-p-site-us-east-1-1077850846.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 172.31.46.66
```

I can see proper html response from `GET http://localhost:3000` or `GET http://localhost:8085` (configured in nginx) within the amazon machine.

I'm using `nginx/1.4.7` as HTTP and reverse proxy server (as per my understanding), conf file being

```
$ vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.soothsayer.co.conf
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream site.soothsayer.co {
     server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8085;
    server_name site-proxy.soothsayer.co site-proxy.soothsayer.co;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site-proxy.soothsayer.co.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://site.soothsayer.co/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**My `/etc/resolv.conf` is,**

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search ec2.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
```

[iptables of amazon machine](https://serverfault.com/a/466071/113713),

```
[root@ip-172-31-42-77 rof]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Security Group on amazon is default**,

```
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8086 0.0.0.0/0
```

I don't see any logs at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. This is what my little brain could debug. I want to fix this issue.

**References**

[nginx, dns - domain.com resolves but subdomain.domain.com doesn't](https://serverfault.com/q/562258/113713)

[AWS - elastic load balancer unable to handle the request](https://serverfault.com/q/614921/113713)

[amazon ec2 instance unable to resolve host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22614664/432903)

[Curl amazon EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070765/432903)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, issue was with load balancer being **internal**. Made it **internet-facing**. Everything looks Majestic now.

[image]

**References**

[Internet-facing and Internal Load Balancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/vpc-loadbalancer-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but your nginx conf with listen 0.0.0.0:8085 may block any remote access.
Try :

```
listen 8085;
```